# Delete a localStorage record based on its timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have got a localStorage record with name **homeCookie** and it's content: **Value1 | 1423415640 | Value3 | Value3**

I need to delete it by jQuery if it's older then it's **timestamp** which is **1423415640**

To get its values I am using the following code:

```
var values = window.localStorage.getItem('homeCookie');
values = values.split('|');
window.opt1 = values[0];
window.opt2 = values[1];
window.opt3 = values[2];
window.opt4 = values[3];
```

Can anyone help me to achieve my task? Remove the whole **homeCookie** record if the **timestamp** older than **now**.

Comment: Why not dump an object as JSON string into localStorage and then just use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Hi @BjornTipling , can you please show the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
if(new Date().getTime() > parseFloat(window.opt2))
    window.localStorage.removeItem('homeCookie')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a time by the moment you add the values

```
var home = 'homeCookie',
    currentTime = new Date();

localStorage.setItem(home + 'time' , currentTime);
```

Later on when retrieving all

```
var values, 
clock = window.localStorage.getItem(home + 'time');

if(outOfTime(clock){
     localStorage.removeItem(home);
} else {
    values = window.localStorage.getItem(home);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help you:

```
var object = {value: "value1", timestamp: '1423415640'};

localStorage.setItem("homeCookie", JSON.stringify(object)); //save Object as json-string

var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("homeCookie")), //parse json-data from localStorage
    expiration = values.timestamp, //get timestamp from "localStorage"-object
    now = new Date().getTime().toString(); //get current timestamp as string

if(now > expiration){
    localStorage.removeItem("homeCookie");   
}
```